# search fast xml file in directory and sub-directory for millions data in c#

Tags: c#, xml

how to search fast in 100 folders of data directory . Here are sample url window

```
    D:\DataDirectory\DataDirectory1\Product
    D:\DataDirectory\DataDirectory1\PB
    ....
    D:\DataDirectory\DataDirectory145\Product
    D:\DataDirectory\DataDirectory145\PB
    D:\DataDirectory\DataDirectory146\Product
    D:\DataDirectory\DataDirectory146\PB
    D:\DataDirectory\DataDirectory147\Product
    D:\DataDirectory\DataDirectory147\PB
```

Here are the sample data of partNo in folder

```
    -Folder Product (contains 122867 items)
    D:\DataDirectory\DataDirectory145\Product\149329762 000007.xml
    D:\DataDirectory\DataDirectory145\Product\149329762 000031.xml
    ....
    D:\DataDirectory\DataDirectory145\Product\149329762 000090.xml
    D:\DataDirectory\DataDirectory145\Product\149329762 000114.xml


    -Folder PWB (contains 125794 items)
    D:\DataDirectory\DataDirectory145\PB\149329762M0000007.xml
    D:\DataDirectory\DataDirectory145\PB\149329762M0000090.xml
    ....
    D:\DataDirectory\DataDirectory145\PB\149329762M0000104.xml
    D:\DataDirectory\DataDirectory145\PB\149329762M0000199.xml
```

This is for search partNo in folder DataDirectory. I've tried search partNo in folder DataDirectory for 6 folder only which are

```
    DataDirectory132, 
    DataDirectory143,
    DataDirectory145,
    DataDirectory146,
    DataDirectory147,
    DataDirectory2
```

but it's take time 8 mins to finish search. Not include search in 147 folders and get the file of data. I'm newbie in c#

Here are code that I've tried

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string partNo = cmbPartNo.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string searchPartNo = "*" + partNo + "*";
            Console.WriteLine("searchPartNo = " + searchPartNo);
            string dirPath = @"D:\DataDirectory";

            // LINQ query.
            var dirs = from dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dirPath,"DataDirectory*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                     select dir;


            // Show results.
            foreach (var dir in dirs)
            {
                 string[] subDirs = Directory.GetFiles(dir, searchPartNo, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                 Console.WriteLine("subDirs = " + subDirs.Length);
                 // Remove path information from string.
                 Console.WriteLine("{0}",
                 dir.Substring(dir.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0} directories found.",
            dirs.Count<string>().ToString());

            // Optionally create a List collection.
            List<string> workDirs = new List<string>(dirs);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UAEx)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(UAEx.Message);
        }
        catch (PathTooLongException PathEx)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(PathEx.Message);
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwEPf.png)

Comment: Sounds like a great use case for a database. Additionally i doubt you will get this much faster (even with a parallel workload) as your bottleneck is most likely your hdd IO

Comment: also `dir.Substring(dir.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1))` is just wrong. Take a look at the `Path` class

Comment: I don't have any knowledge in c# & just copy the coding from internet.. 
        dir.Substring(dir.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1)) i don't know the funct of this.. i usually use php mysql

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following code last year and curious how much faster the code runs than your code.  My code does a dir one folder at a time using TopDirectoryOnly instead of AllDirectories.  I suspect searching down all the folder is what is slowing down the code.

For comparison purposes you may not want to write to output file test.xml.  I would put the output file in a different folder than where you xml files are located.  The code recursively goes down each folder and writes all the filename and fileinfo to the output file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace WriteFileNamesXml
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string FOLDER = @"c:\temp";
        static XmlWriter writer = null;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            writer.WriteStartDocument(true);

            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(FOLDER);
            WriteTree(info);

            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();


        }
        static long WriteTree(DirectoryInfo info)
        {
            long size = 0;
            writer.WriteStartElement("Folder");
            try
            {
                writer.WriteAttributeString("name", info.Name);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberSubFolders", info.GetDirectories().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberFiles", info.GetFiles().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());


                foreach (DirectoryInfo childInfo in info.GetDirectories())
                {
                    size += WriteTree(childInfo);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception Folder : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
            }

            FileInfo[] fileInfo = null;
            try
            {
                fileInfo = info.GetFiles();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception FileInfo : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
            }

            if (fileInfo != null)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo finfo in fileInfo)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement("File");
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("name", finfo.Name);
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("size", finfo.Length.ToString());
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        size += finfo.Length;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception File : {0}, Error : {1}", finfo.FullName, ex.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                        writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
                    }
                }
            }

            writer.WriteElementString("size", size.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            return size;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry i'm still not understand.. T.T